# Change Quasar Notify icon color

Tags: quasar-framework

I have a notification displayed by Quasar notify that includes an icon. How can I change that icon's color?

I can't find a way via the normal options

I don't want to use plain CSS from the caller because I'm using this in multiple places and created a service to display

I tried using the `html: true` options but in the message if I use `<q-icon>` it doesn't render

```
static notify(text: string) {
  Notify.create({
    message: text,
    icon: 'check_circle',
    position: 'top-right'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one thing create `class` that change the icon color and add that class in default.

```
import { Notify } from 'quasar'

Notify.setDefaults({
  classes:'Your class'
})
```

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/jOLvGQj